# How to get the count of subchild inside the parent div in javascript or in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know how to count the div's of subchildren inside the parent div maybe someone can help me with this. I'm not that good in javascript or in Jquery.

Here's my code:

```
$(function () {
    var parent = document.getElementById('parent').children;
    var cnt = 0;
    if (parent) {
        var match = 'child';
        for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
            var temp = parent[i].getAttribute('id');
            if (temp.indexOf(match) == 0) {
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(cnt);
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aldrin27/Ld2odLjn/)**

Comment: You're not using jQuery at all. Why ask about it, and why "introduce it" into your code base if its not needed?

Comment: Yes but i know there's a code that will get my desired output using jquery.

Comment: you can do it without jQuery in a very simple manner (one liner even), see my answer. I don't believe in going to bloated libraries for simple tasks.

Comment: Please edit your question, include the relevant HTML, and explain ***exactly*** what you're trying to count, cause your current question is not what you're asking for in comments to answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [attribute-value](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector

`[id^=subchild]` will select all the elements whose `id` value starts with(`^`) `child`.

[Attribute value starts with selector.](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Ld2odLjn/4/)

```js
$(function() {
  var subchildrenLen = $('#parent [id^=subchild]').length;
  $('body').append('No of children = ' + subchildrenLen);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">
    <div id="subchild1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
    <div id="subchild2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child3">
    <div id="subchild3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can also use `querySelectorAll` with the same selector if you don't want to use jQuery.

```
var subchildrens = document.querySelectorAll('#parent [id^=subchild]').length;
```

If you want all the descendents count

```
var allChildrens = document.querySelectorAll('#parent div').length
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir @Tushar. I'll accept that within the moment.

Comment: That's not *exactly* what OP code does. You catch the any div within parent (any nesting level) with the ID starting with "subchild". Original code only looks 1 level deep and looks for "child". But of course it's an easy fix.

Comment: To match it exactly I'd make it `#parent>[id^=child]`.

Comment: @Amit Yes, that will be bit efficient

Comment: @aldrin27 The question is bit confusing as what exactly you want `$('#parent > [id^=child]').length` will give you the direct children having id starting with `child`. If you want subchildrens use `$('#parent [id^=subchild]').length`, the same selectors can be used in Vanilla JS `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: I only want to count the subchilds.

Comment: @aldrin27 You mean elements whose id starts with `subchilds`, okay updating answer. Anyway you've got the idea :)

Comment: @Tushar exactly as what is written in the question. my answer is valid right?

Answer (score 2):

```
alert($('#parent').find('div[id*="subchild"]').length)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld2odLjn/5/)

> Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]

[DOCUMENTATION](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: This will be bad choice as OP wants to select direct childrens(_can be seen from the code in question_) and `div[id*="child"]` will give result `6`. Side effects of `*`

Comment: @Tushar that is why the selector text i used is subchild since he wants subchild.

Comment: Kindly check the code in question. Notice `var match = 'child';` and `if (temp.indexOf(match) == 0) {
                cnt++;
            }`

Comment: @Tushar code maybe wrong but the question states `div's of subchildren` clearly one can say he wants the div with `subchild` `ids` we can assume that the code is a bit off

Comment: I was confused about what OP wants, your answer is also valid

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery at all here, simply use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and examine the length of the returned *NodeList*

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#parent>[id^=child]').length)
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
        <div id="subchild1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
        <div id="subchild2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="child3">
        <div id="subchild3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: one question you will also get the number of child div here right?i think OP only wants the subchild.

Comment: @Pekka that imitates precisely what OP code does. If intentions are different, it should be noted.

Comment: _To match it exactly I'd make it `#parent>[id^=child]`._ same is applicable to you :)

Comment: @Amit OP wants the subchildrens, see the comments on my answer, you need to update your answer to make it valid

Comment: @Tushar - thanks, but no thanks. answers should solve requests in comments, they should solve the question as it is posted. otherwise when someone comes to this question in 6 months time and says: "Hey, that's exactly what I need! lets see the answers" they'll get an answer that doesn't match the question, will be confused and find the code not working. that's not how SO is designed.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert($('#parent [id^=subchild]').length)
});
```

[DEMO PAGE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/Ld2odLjn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Since `subchild` is child of `div` which is child of `#parent`, You  can use selector `#parent > div > div`, **[`>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)** is **[direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)**

```js
$(function() {
  var len = $('#parent > div > div').length;
  alert(len);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">
    <div id="subchild1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
    <div id="subchild2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child3">
    <div id="subchild3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using JavaScript you can use **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**

```js
var len = document.querySelectorAll('#parent > div > div').length;
alert(len);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">
    <div id="subchild1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
    <div id="subchild2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child3">
    <div id="subchild3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```